# Michael H artl Ch 10 Tutorial NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_sent_at='

Tags: ruby-on-rails

10 tutorial and has come up with this error

```
ERROR["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 2016-04-14 20:33:23 +0800]
 test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (1460637203.22s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_sent_at=' for #<User:0x007f942d13d620>
            app/models/user.rb:56:in `create_reset_digest'
            app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
            test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
        app/models/user.rb:56:in `create_reset_digest'
        app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
        test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'

  33/33: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.61023s
33 tests, 143 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here's my user model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest
      ...

  #set the password reset attributes
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    self.update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    self.update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end
```

Here's my controller code

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instruction"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And Finally here's my test!

```
class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @user.email }
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # Wrong Email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email Right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
      email: user.email,
      user:  { password: "foobaz", password_confirmation: "barquux" }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Blank password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
      email: user.email,
      user:  { password: "  ", password_confirmation: "foobar" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    # valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
      email: user.email,
      user:  { password: "foobaz", password_confirmation: "foobaz" }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
  end
end
```

My app itself is working fine. So I'm not sure if i wrote the test wrong or something in my applicationn is wrong. Please help!

Comment: Post the user_params method from your users_controller.rb.

Answer (score 0):

If your app itself is working fine, and only the test is breaking, then there is one thing I can guess is the fault:

The attribute `reset_sent_at` is not available in the `test` environment.

To solve this, try to run your migrations for the `test` environment as follow:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

This can easily be the only thing you need done.